# How did the terms stress and strain come to describe two different things?

Tags: physics, terminology

In physics, stress essentially captures *forces* in a body, where as strain captures *displacements*. Two dimensionally very different concepts. If you look it up in a thesaurus, stress and strain are synonyms. How did they come to denote such different things in physics?

Comment: Very good question. This has bothered me for 20 years. It would also be nice to how how other languages describe stress and strain. German has stress-strain diagram = Spannungs-Dehnungs-Diagramm (Google), Dehnungs denotes some expansion which is more descriptive.

Comment: Technical English and everyday English (much like technical vs everyday in the other languages I've learned) are not the same. This is generally true of any specialty (see, for example, law) in order to be precise.

Comment: As @JonCuster said, many many words in any given specialty mean different things from their meaning in everyday language.  Each specialty needs to be able to distinguish disjunct concepts.